# AWS Batch Fargate not Concurrent when job required vcpu is more than 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I am deploying multiple jobs on AWS batch with Fargate Model in ap-south-1. If I deploy jobs with 2 vcpu atleast 3 are executing concurrently. But with anything more than 2 vcpu its Executing sequentially, only one at a time. My compute environment has 256 vcpu limit. No other queue is assigned to this CE. No other batch job is running in that account, but still it is limited to one. and each job takes 10-30 minutes to complete. Can anyone help me?.

Thanks.